# Opacity change icons on scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

new user here.
I'm having an issue with a javascript command I've written in my html.
So my page is set up in 3 sections. The sections are represented by 3 icons on a fixed nav bar. What I'm trying to do is have the other two icons opacity decrease depending on what section you scroll to.
I wrote an if-else statement to get it to work and it does for the first section, but when I write a new if-else statement for the next section the next opacity change isn't recognized.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nav = $(".work1");
    var banner = $("#LogoBio");
    var pos = nav.position();
    var icon1 = $("#Graphics");
    var icon2 = $("#Animations");
    var icon3 = $("#HandArt");
    var section1 = $("#ill4");
    var section2 = $("#aniDes");

    $(window).scroll(function(){
         var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

         if (windowpos>=banner.outerHeight()){
             nav.addClass('fixedTop');
         }
         else {
             nav.removeClass('fixedTop');
             }

    $(".work1").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner"</div>');


    if (windowpos>=section1.outerHeight()){
        icon2.addClass('opacityChange'); 
        icon3.addClass('opacityChange');

        }
    else {
            icon2.removeClass('opacityChange');
            icon3.removeClass('opacityChange');
        }
        });
    });
```

If-else statement for next section?

If anyone has any ideas on a solution I would so appreciate it. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: where is section3?

Comment: Hey thanks for the prompt response bro.
I haven't even added section 3 in yet. I was just trying to get the first two working.

Answer (score 0):

first add class attribute to your icon tags:

<.... id="Graphics" class='icon' ...>

<.... id="Animations" class='icon' ...>

<.... id="HandArt" class='icon' ...>

then, in code first add class to all .icon tags and after it remove that from unwanted ones:

```
$(".icon").addClass("opacityChange");
if (windowpos>=section3.outerHeight()) {
    icon3.removeClass("opacityChange");
} else if (windowpos>=section2.outerHeight()) {
    icon2.removeClass("opacityChange");
} else if (windowpos>=section1.outerHeight()) {
    icon1.removeClass("opacityChange");
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out, thanks a lot for the help SalmanAA!